# EditText inputtype "time" does not support colons?

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

Designing my layout, I selected an EditText with the format "time", and it put

```
android:inputType="time"
```

in my XML file. But now when I run the app, Android opens the soft keyboard which only offers numbers and number signs like "-", "." etc., but no colons as required for a correct time format ("##:##")...

Did anyone already find a way to offer an easy way to enter times (00:00-24:00) apart from using the gigantic graphical controls?

Comment: If by "gigantic graphical controls" you mean TimePicker, then it's the best way to ask user to enter time. It's a lot more easier then typing it on the keyboard, so you should not overcomplicate your application.

Comment: I have the same issue for a samsung tablet. If keyboard opens there are just numbers but no ":" which would be needed to insert time format according to "hh:mm". Really don't get it how this should work?

Comment: seems to be a known bug for samsung devices see here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36943744

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@richey Change your keyboard sittings in the emulator and you are able to input : as well as am or pm 
thanks

Comment: the idea is to have all possible characters ready for input as far as I understand Android's input types ... which is not the case with the "time" format. However, you are describing something like a workaround and since no one else came up with a better explanation or suggestion till now, I'll accept that as the best answer so far ;-)